# Forever on ubuntu

Tags: node.js, ubuntu

I am working on node.js where forever is installed. I am not sure where is intalled . when i go to project directory then type command `forever list` then it will display no forever

Can any body tell me how to check and how to resart processes.

My website is running. it means forever may be running

Answer (score 1):

If `forever list` is empty, your nodeJS app is not running.

You have to start it first by doing `forever start yourApp.js`

Comment: return binding.open(pathModule._makeLong(path), stringToFlags(flags), mode);
Error: EACCES, permission denied '/home/ubuntu/.forever/v34A.log'

Comment: You have some rights problem. forever is unable to create its log file. Which user are you using ?

Comment: what kind of problems? Can you please tellme

Comment: The directory /home/ubuntu/.forever is not writeable. You can bypass the log target by setting the -l parameter with forever. `forever start yourAPp.js -l somewhere/logfile.log`

Answer (score 0):

You have to install forever with sudo.